# Removing xml annotations from Android classes using Proguard

Tags: java, android, gradle, gson, proguard

I have a project set up in Android Studio that is relying on a jar file that is imported from a remote repository by Gradle. This means no "/libs" folder.

This jar file contains a bunch of JAXB objects with xml annotations that look like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Accounts", propOrder = {
    "account"
})
```

However, on the Android side, I am using Gson to serialize these objects. I didn't think these annotations would be a problem, but Gson is detecting them via reflection. I would like to remove them using ProGuard, but have no idea where to start, or if it's even possible.

I think I want to use the -libraryjars flag in my configuration file, but don't know how to get a dynamic path to a jar file imported by Gradle. The documentation for using ProGuard for Android hasn't been very helpful so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android documentation explains how to enable ProGuard in your builds (Ant, Eclipse, or Gradle). Once it is enabled:

1. ProGuard's shrinking step removes annotations if they appear to be unused in the code. If Gson uses the annotations, they probably won't be removed.
2. ProGuard's obfuscation step removes *all* annotations by default, unless the configuration specifies:

   ```
   -keepattributes *Annotation*
   ```

   The global configuration file in the Android SDK, `android-sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt`, contains this line, because most developers want to preserve annotations. If you comment it out, all annotations will be removed.